# What Batman stories follow on from "Skulduggery" by Brian K. Vaughan, with the 'Skeleton' character?

Tags: dc, batman

At the end of 'Skulduggery' there is a short character introduction for "Skeleton" that came from "Batman: Gotham City Secret Files and Origins". It is just a small couple of pages to introduce the villain, but I found it really integrating and would like to read on.

Does anyone know what books continue from this character introduction so I can read the rest of this story for Skeleton that started with "Skulduggery"?

I know the original writer left Batman but did another writer pick up this story or did it just fade into nothingness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one appearance of the Skeleton, that story from *Secret Files and Origins*, which was collected in the *False Faces* trade.

BKV had this to say in a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/1vquaa/we_are_brian_k_vaughan_and_marcos_martin/):

> The Skeleton! Yeah, he was a new Batman character Marcos and I
>   created, a mysterious villain who impersonated other villains to cover
>   his tracks in his weirdly personal campaign against Bruce Wayne.
>
> We had plans for a year-long story, and I still remember who we were
>   going to ultimately reveal the Skeleton to be, but that mystery is
>   probably more interesting remaining one.
>
> I love the Big Two, but I got to write just about every character I
>   ever wanted to for each, so I’m very happy just creating new stuff for
>   the rest of my career.

More on [Left Unresolved](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2015/01/22/left-unresolved-who-was-the-batman-villain-the-skeleton/).

After *Skullduggery* he wrote the *False Faces* story, which was essentially an audition for the Batman writers role. Ultimately he didn't get the regular gig on Batman, which may have seen the Skeleton return. I believe that it went to Ed Brubaker, IIRC, and that was it for the Skeleton.

Comment: If that's what the story was supposed to be I suggest reading Under the Hood and HUSH, both of which seem to use a very similar story.

Answer (score 2):

You've read everything he's been in apparently.

[Here](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/skeleton/4005-67326/) is the list:

1. Batman: False Faces
2. Batman: Gotham City Secret Files